# Kohana Validation Regex - Must have lower and upper character

Tags: php, regex, kohana

I am using the following regex

```
->rule('password','regex', array(':value', "(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])"))
```

but Kohana is complaining that '(' is an Unknown modifier. Is there another way to regex a string to make sure it has 1 or more lower and 1 or more upper letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP expects additional delimiters around its regexes (and mistook the first set of parentheses for your delimiters). Use

```
->rule('password','regex', array(':value', "/(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])/"))
```

And perhaps anchor it to the start of the string. That way the regex will only be tested once if it fails, not once for each character in the string:

```
->rule('password','regex', array(':value', "/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

`~([a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z])~`

?

See http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Validate#regex

Comment: @Tim Pitzcker: Right. Edited.